# Core data not triggering immediate refresh with SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I'm at a loss with this problem I've been troubleshooting the past few days.

I am drawing a custom shape, and the user can move one of the points around via a drag gesture. I want the shape to redraw, live, when moving the point around.

Here is some sample code that is working using CGPoint.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ShapeTest: Shape {
    
    @State var points: [CGPoint]
    @State var closed: Bool = true
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        if (points.count > 0) {
            path.move(to: points.first!)
            path.addLines(points)
            if closed { path.closeSubpath() }
        }
        return path
    }
}

struct RedrawEdgeTestCGPoint: View {
    
    @State var points = [CGPoint]()
    @State var originalPosition: CGPoint? = nil
    
    private var movePointDragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged { value in
                if points.isEmpty {
                    return
                }
                
                if originalPosition == nil {
                    originalPosition = CGPoint(x: points.last!.x, y: points.last!.y)
                }
                
                let lastIndex = points.count - 1
                points[lastIndex].x = originalPosition!.x + value.translation.width
                points[lastIndex].y = originalPosition!.y + value.translation.height
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                originalPosition = nil
            }
    }
    
    private var addNewPointGesture: some Gesture {
        TapGesture(count: 2)
            .onEnded {
                points.append(CGPoint())
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Group {
                ShapeTest(points: points)
                    .stroke()
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .gesture(movePointDragGesture.simultaneously(with: addNewPointGesture))
        }
    }
}

struct RedrawEdgeTestCGPoint_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RedrawEdgeTestCGPoint()
    }
}
```

Now, here is another code sample. This example is generally the same thing, but this is using a Point entity I've defined in Core Data instead of CGPoint.

```
import SwiftUI

struct RedrawEdgeTestCoreData: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @State var points: [Point] = []
    @State var originalPosition: CGPoint? = nil
    
    private var movePointDragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged { value in
                if points.isEmpty {
                    return
                }
                
                if originalPosition == nil {
                    originalPosition = CGPoint(x: points.last!.x, y: points.last!.y)
                }
                
                let lastIndex = points.count - 1
                points[lastIndex].x = originalPosition!.x + value.translation.width
                points[lastIndex].y = originalPosition!.y + value.translation.height
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                originalPosition = nil
            }
    }
    
    private var addNewPointGesture: some Gesture {
        TapGesture(count: 2)
            .onEnded {
                points.append(Point(context: viewContext))
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Group {
                ShapeTest(points: points.map { CGPoint(x: $0.x, y: $0.y) })
                    .stroke()
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .gesture(movePointDragGesture.simultaneously(with: addNewPointGesture))
        }
    }
}

struct RedrawEdgeTestCoreData_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RedrawEdgeTestCoreData()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

The version utilizing Core Data does not update while dragging. It will redraw when I double tap to add another point.

Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: CoreData arrays are updated when you add or remove an element from them,
but they do not update when you change an individual element.
Totally un-tested, but you could try adding `try viewContext.save()` after you update the
 points in `onChanged`.

Comment: CoreData models are reference types and, in fact, they conform to `ObservableObject`. `@State` doesn't work properly with reference types (it only catches add/delete actions on arrays). I'd suggest moving them to a `@Published` property on a separate `ObservableObject` and then calling `objectWillChange.send()` manually when you change the array.

Comment: Wrap the CoreData object in an `@ObservedObject`, not the array but the `Point`

Comment: Thanks, all. I have some new things to try out this evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the approach suggested by jnpdx and it works.

```
import SwiftUI

class PointsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var points = [Point]()
    
    func movePoint(index: Int, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
        points[index].x = x
        points[index].y = y
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}

struct RedrawEdgeTestCoreData: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: PointsViewModel
    @State var originalPosition: CGPoint? = nil
    
    private var movePointDragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged { value in
                if viewModel.points.isEmpty {
                    return
                }
                
                if originalPosition == nil {
                    originalPosition = CGPoint(x: viewModel.points.last!.x, y: viewModel.points.last!.y)
                }
                
                let lastIndex = viewModel.points.count - 1
                viewModel.movePoint(index: lastIndex, x: originalPosition!.x + value.translation.width, y: originalPosition!.y + value.translation.height)
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                originalPosition = nil
            }
    }
    
    private var addNewPointGesture: some Gesture {
        TapGesture(count: 2)
            .onEnded {
                viewModel.points.append(Point(context: viewContext))
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                ShapeTest(points: viewModel.points.map { CGPoint(x: $0.x, y: $0.y) })
                    .stroke()
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .gesture(movePointDragGesture.simultaneously(with: addNewPointGesture))
        }
    }
}

struct RedrawEdgeTestCoreData_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RedrawEdgeTestCoreData(viewModel: PointsViewModel())
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```